# Android - How to start a new activity

Tags: java, android, android-activity, drawing

I'm trying to make a bull's eye with random color, and instead of circles I will use squares.

But the thing is that when I run the app on the emulator and when he starts the new activity it stops responding.

This is the main activity, the one that starts the DrawActivity.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Intent coiso = new Intent(this, Draw.class);
        startActivity(coiso);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

And this is the Draw activity, the one that I want to start. (It doesn't have the things that I want to do. Because I can't, the problem is ahead)

```
public class Draw extends View {

    public Draw(Context context) {
        super(context);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onDraw(canvas);   
    }
}
```

Can someone help me? Sorry for the english.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have this

```
 public class Draw extends View
```

Your class does not extend Activity

Instead you can do as below

```
Draw draw = new Draw(this); 
setContentView(draw);
```

Or have a layout linear or relative and place it where you like add your Draw view to the layout after initializing.

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);
// linear layout or relative layout in activity_main.xml.
// place the layout ahere you want along with other views  
Draw draw = new Draw(this); 
ll.addView(draw);  
// add your customview to linearlayout
```

Edit:

Remove this

```
 Intent coiso = new Intent(this, Draw.class);
 startActivity(coiso);
```

In your activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
     // customize linear layout to your needs. 
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    </LinearLayout>
      // other widgets
</RelativeLayout>
```

In your onCreate

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);
Draw draw = new Draw(this); 
ll.addView(draw);
```

Comment: I'm really sorry, but it was not very clear to me. Can you explain better?

Comment: @NunoBatalha which part is not clear to you the 1st method or the second one?

Comment: 2nd method. I now understand that is needs to extend activity to be started as one. But in that way I couldn't heritage the methods from View.

Comment: @NunoBatalha since its a view there is no need for startActivity. check the edit. tell me if it still not clear

Comment: Well, I made it, thanks! But there are some things to explain. Why to have a linear layout inside of a relative layout? Could I draw in the relative layout? I want to have as plenty space I can. And can you explain me this part? Draw draw = new Draw(this);

Comment: `Draw draw = new Draw(this)` initializing your draw view. You are adding your draw to linearlayout which is part of your activity_main.xml which is set to the activty. instead of linear alyout you can have relative layout also. Customize to have plenty of space. Or instead of all that. you can set the content of your custom view to the activity like `Draw draw = new Draw(this); 
setContentView(draw)` which occupies entire screen. your view is added to the activity. and `this` refers to the activity context

Comment: @NunoBatalha instead of thanks if it helps mark the answer as accepted. it will others who visit the post.

Comment: Nice man, very thankful! I have learned some nice things that i didn't realize! I've marked as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your `Draw` class needs to `extend` `Activity` rather than `View`. As you want to start a new `Activity`, the `Draw` class, this means that this should extend `Activity`. Also, you need to Override `onCreate()` within the `Draw` class.

If your Draw class is a View, then I would suggest that you add the view to the `Layout` that you are using using the [`addView()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#addView%28android.view.View%29)

Answer (score 0):

startActivity requires an activity. I would suggest going through the docs
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivity(android.content.Intent)

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that you change `Draw extends Activity`
You cant intent to a new activity with no layout and no OnCreate As far as I know.
try creating a regular activity which extends `Activity` and implement your Draw there.

```
public class DrawActivity extends Activity {

@SuppressLint("ShowToast")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_draw);
    Toast.makeText(DrawActivity.this, "YO", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
}
```

and from there implement your draw functions. 
or create a JAVA class which implements your draw needs and use it in main screen.